# In PySpark is there any way to dynamically register UDF using functions of Python class given at run time?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am new to Python, so apologizing if there is any mistake in my approach

I have a scenario where client can provide its custom Python functions and wants to register them as UDF in PySpark.

Based on my initial understanding, I am expecting a function which return a dictionary of function name and function definition, from importing module and calling this method at run time.

Random Custom function class example

```py
    class CustomFuntions():

        def reverse_statement(self, statement):
            temp_list = statement.split(' ')
            temp_list.reverse()
            return ' '.join(temp_list)

        def get_functions(self):
            return {
                "rev_statement" : self.reverse_statement
                }
```

Registration Part

```py
    from importlib import import_module

    class UDFRegistration():

        def __init__(self, spark):
            self.spark = spark

        def get_function_dict(self, module_name, class_name, method_name):
            instance = getattr(import_module(module_name), class_name)
            func_dict = getattr(instance(), method_name)()
            return func_dict

        def register_udf(self, module_name, class_name, method_name):
            f_dict = self.get_function_dict(module_name, class_name, method_name)

            for func_name, func_def in f_dict.items():
                self.spark.udf.register(func_name, func_def)
```

Main class

```py
    CUST_UDF_MODULE = 'custom_functions'
    CUST_UDF_CLASS = 'CustomFuntions'
    CUST_UDF_METHOD = 'get_functions'

    if __name__ == '__main__':

        spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
        spark.sparkContext.addPyFile("custom_functions.py")

        print('Registering custom UDF')
        udf_reg = UDFRegistration(spark)
        udf_reg.register_udf(CUST_UDF_MODULE, CUST_UDF_CLASS, CUST_UDF_METHOD)

        spark.sql('select rev_statement(\'!!! WORLD HELLO\')').show()
```

Getting following error while running it on local machine.

*Console Output*

```
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Registering custom UDF
19/05/30 12:17:57 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec.evaluate(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(EvalPythonExec.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(EvalPythonExec.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 30 more
19/05/30 12:17:57 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:97)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec.evaluate(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:77)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(EvalPythonExec.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(EvalPythonExec.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:801)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 30 more

19/05/30 12:17:57 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\eclipse-workspace\Workspace\SparkMain.py", line 31, in <module>
    spark.sql('select rev_statement(\'!!! WORLD HELLO\')').show()
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py", line 378, in show
    print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o30.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:155)

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:97)

    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:117)

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:108)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec.evaluate(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:77)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(EvalPythonExec.scala:127)

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.EvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(EvalPythonExec.scala:89)

    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(
```

Comment: _Cannot run program "python": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified_ doesn't seem to have anything to do with the code you've shared (which looks reasonable). More a problem with system configuration.

Answer (score 0):

As highlighted by [user10938362](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10938362/user10938362) the issue was on *system configuration side* & not on *code side*

After setting PYSPARK_PYTHON in PyDev interpreter of eclipse, code executed successfully

> PYSPARK_PYTHON =  C:\Users\User\anaconda3\python.exe