# What can be an efficient design for a rule based engine in pypark running in AWS glue and rule repository as Dynamo DB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue

We are trying to come up with a design to be implemented in AWS for a rule engine. Below is the explanation of the scenario.

1. We are building a data lake on AWS using S3 as storage having different buckets to represent data enrichment. For example data lands into raw bucket. From there data is picked and data standardization is applied (some of the standardization are making boolean field uniform like having value 0 or 1, converting all date format column intoa  unform standard like dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss, trimming spaces for certain column data etc.)
2. The data movement is done using glue jobs, pyspark code, Step function for orchestration and Dynamodb for storing configuration for the jobs and Glue catalog for storing metadata.

The need is to store the standardization rules in such a way in Dynamodb so that the glue job can pick up the standardization rules from DynamoDB table and apply them to the data that the job is processing. Data to be process will be stored in S3 and picked up in a dataframe.

What can be the best way to do it dynamically. Also the job should be flexible enough so that in future if a new rule is added in the dynamoDB table it should be picked up and applied on the data getting process by the glue job (we do not want to change the code of the job if new rule gets added). Rules must be in DynamoDB so that other processes can dynamically consume/manipulate them and that Glue should always retrieve the latest version to use in a job.

Any idea with sample code will be really helpful. Thanks!!

So if I summarize the steps in glue code it should run like below:

1. Glue job picks one data table from S3 bucket (either through catalog or connection)
2. Then picks rules from dynamo db. The rule should have the information of what rule and on which column to apply of the table picked in step1
3. Apply the rule dynamically either using spark sql or spark api on the data frame
4. end

Comment: You explain that you want your Glue jobs to be dynamic and pick up configurations stored in a DynamoDB, but why? What's the added benefit of having them somewhere else? I'm just asking to better understand your use case and see if DynamoDB is the proper choice.

Comment: The dynamoDB table is the choice of config store because this table will be referred by other processes as well in the overall architecture. I do not want bring all of the other processes here in this discussion otherwise motive of the question will be defeated.

Comment: Okay, it makes sense, and we don't need to know the other components. You should consider updating your question to specify that rules must be in DynamoDB so that other processes can dynamically consume/manipulate them and that Glue should always retrieve the latest version to use in a job.

Comment: Thanks will do :)

Answer (score 1):

A kind of guidance is provided in the below link.

[In PySpark is there any way to dynamically register UDF using functions of Python class given at run time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56373434/in-pyspark-is-there-any-way-to-dynamically-register-udf-using-functions-of-pytho)

Using the concept provided in the link, dynamic rule engine can be developed. The glue job which is supposed to process data can read the configuration details stored in dynamo DB.
The right kind of configuration to be stored in DynamoDB will be rule name, table name, map of (column name and rules to be applied). Then in the job this configuration can be looped through and sql query string to run in spark sql can be dynamically built and run in loop.

This is a design question hence I am not posting extra code apart from the details already provided in the link.

Answer (score 0):

AWS Glue has native support to read/write to and from DynamoDB Tables. In your case, if you only need to retrieve data you can configure DynamoDB as a Source for your jobs.

```py
import sys
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])
glue_context= GlueContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate())
job = Job(glue_context)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)

dyf = glue_context.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    connection_type="dynamodb",
    connection_options={
        "dynamodb.input.tableName": "test_source",
        "dynamodb.throughput.read.percent": "1.0",
        "dynamodb.splits": "100"
    }
)
```

You can find more details on this code and the configuration at [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect.html) of the official documentation.

If instead you want to manage this in a less pyspark-y (but more pythonic) way, you have the option of importing the `boto3` library (official AWS SDK for Python) and pull the data from there.

```py
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.service('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table('my_table')
table.query(
  Select='ALL_ATTRIBUTES',
  KeyConditions={
    'my_partition_key': { "S": "some_value" }
  }
)
```

[Here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#service-resource) you can find the official documentation for the `boto3` library. You have different options to read data but generally speaking you should always try to use `query` over `scan` when possible.

In both cases you will have to make sure that AWs Glue has enough permission to perform read and list operation on the DynamoDB table you want to use, and on DynamoDB's side that the table has enough Read/Write output to sustain the operation.

Comment: Sorry Andre. My explanation of the question was so bad that you completely misunderstood. This is more a design question. After looking into your answer. I have re framed the question. Kindly read it once more and see if you can suggest me any good idea.